# Choose a drop down option using Selenium Python Webscraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium and python webscraping to choose a drop down option of routes based on my local public transit schedule. Here is the link to the site: https://tmweb.pacebus.com/TMWebWatch/LiveDepartureTimes

The issue I'm running into is that the line:

```
find_route_takin = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"active-result")
```

produces an error saying:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".active-result"}
```

Here is the code for how I am trying to complete the task:

```
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://tmweb.pacebus.com/TMWebWatch/LiveDepartureTimes")

driver.find_element(By.ID, "MainContent_routeList_chosen")

find_route_takin = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"active-result")
select_route = Select(find_route_takin)
select_route.select_by_visible_text("565 - Grand Avenue")
time.sleep(20)
```

Within the HTML of the site for the first drop-down for the routes, there is a `ul` object that holds many `li` objects that represent each individual route. I have tried looking through various YouTube videos, but I can't find a solution to my problem. I've read that perhaps I'll have to use xpath instead of CLASS_NAME, but when I tried copying the xpath by right-clicking and choosing copy xpath, I'm still prompted with the same error message. What I want is when I run the program, a chrome window is brought up and the 565 - Grand Avenue route is selected. The error I'm running into is

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".active-result"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this way:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = Chrome(options=options)

def choose_route(opt):

    driver.get("https://tmweb.pacebus.com/TMWebWatch/LiveDepartureTimes")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'MainContent_routeList_chosen'))).click()

    routes = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.chosen-results')
    route_options = routes.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')

    for option in route_options:
        if option.text == opt:
            option.click()

    time.sleep(10)

choose_route("565 - Grand Avenue")
# choose_route("213 - Green Bay Road")
```

Things to note:

1. first we wait for the `Route` drop-down to get visibly located/loaded on the page in order to click it.
2. As we click, the drop-down gets open, and all the options get loaded on the page. So we find all the route options which are all the `li` tags under the `ul` tag with class name `chosen-results`
3. And finally choose the option based on the text and click.

That's all, and notice that we can not use `Select` because the drop-down options are not under a `select` tag.

Comment: Thank you Ajeet, this has been a very annoying problem that I'm glad to have had help in solving.